# weird grey background appeared when the page is loading on iOS app

Tags: ios, debugging, colors, background

Does anyone know what's wrong with the grey background here? It only happens when the page is loading. Please see the below screenshot. I'm new to IOS development and I would like to know how I could start debugging this issue. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Is there any background which you set? Also are you created this view programatically?

Comment: @Vino I didn't write the code. But what I found so far is that it's programmatically. But what possible problems are there?

Comment: Can you share some code ?